# Count unique values using countifs?

Tags: excel, countif, count-unique

I'm trying to create a gift table. Here is some sample data:

```
Gift    Donor ID
$1      100
$1      151
$2      100
$2      186
$2      124
$4      124
$4      178
$4      162
$5      100
$5      158
```

In column A I've written a formula that counts the number of gifts greater then $1 and less than or equal to $4. There are 6.

```
 =COUNTIFS(A2:A11,">1",A2:A11,"<=4")
```

Now what I need to do is count the number of unique donors from column B who meet the criteria from column A. In this case there are 5. What would that formula look like?

Comment: I'm not sure what that would look like. I just tried it without much success.

Comment: Pivot table definitely the way to go.  You can group the results if you want $5.00 and $5.01 to appear in the same row.

Comment: Unfortunately in this case I'm the grunt creating the spreadsheet for the pro to analyze. Your link was helpful. I ended up creating a helper row and using the answer provided there.

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer a conventional formula approach, you can perform this with an *array formula* version of a standard *count unique with SUMPRODUCT*.

`=SUM(IFERROR((($A$2:$A$99>1)*($A$2:$A$99<=4))/COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$99,">1",$A$2:$A$99,"<=4",$B$2:$B$99,$B$2:$B$99&""),0))`

Finalize with `Ctrl+Shift+Enter` rather than simply `Enter`.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest an approach by adding two columns.
A column named *skipped* (this naming is important here!) with below formula:

```
=IF(AND(A2 > 1, A2 <= 4), B2, "skipped")
```

And another column named *counted* with below formula:

```
=MATCH(C2, C:C, 0) = ROW()
```

> Note: if found item is first item its result will be equal to its row.

Now your formulas will be simpler like these:

```
=COUNT(C2:C11)                    => 6
=COUNTIF(D2:D11, TRUE)            => 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Use FILTER to get a list of donor IDs matching the criteria.  Then apply UNIQUE to that, and then finally use COUNTA to count the elements (that aren't blank):

```
=COUNTA(UNIQUE(FILTER(B2:B11, (A2:A11>1)*(A2:A11<=4))))
```

FILTER takes two arguments*, the range you are filtering and an array of true/false values the same size.  Generally, this will be something like range=x or some similar condition, which will evaluate to an array of booleans, but if you need to use multiple conditions you multiply them, like (rng1=x)*(rng2=y).  That's this part:

```
(A2:A11>1)*(A2:A11<=4)
```

Google Sheets, however, will accept comma separated lists of conditions, which is a little easier to work with.

```
=COUNTA(UNIQUE(FILTER(B2:B11, A2:A11>1, A2:A11<=4)))
```

Let me know if that does what you need.

* actually three.  The last one is the value to return if no matches are found in the filter condition.  Default is a CALC error, I believe.